# How to write intermediate logic for fb chatbot with wit.ai?

Tags: nlp, chatbot, wit.ai, facebook-chatbot

I'm creating a facebook chatbot and using wit.ai for NLP. The replies I'm sending to user needs lots of processing (like db fetch, db update etc.). So whatever user is sending, I'm forwarding it to wit just to identify the context. Based on wit's reply, I'm implementing my own logic and creating reply. So, my code is becoming like lots of switch cases to categorise the context and creating response. Is there any optimal way to handle intermediate logic?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Node.js** server running as a middleware solution.